# what is the best resource for JSON for a beginner

Tags: xml, json

i have never used JSON and want to find more about it as people keep referring to it as  a better version of XML for sending data from client to server.

can someone please suggest a good resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON for the masses](http://www.dustindiaz.com/json-for-the-masses/) is pretty straightforward.

If you understand XML, you can understand:

http://json.org/

And last, but not least, the [obligatory list of resources](http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Programming/JSON/JSONArticles/tabid/2296/Default.aspx), and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is:

www.json.org

Keep in mind that JSON and XML are different things, as explained in some or the articles linked in that site.

But if it's just for sending data, usually JSON is more compact than XML.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is very simple, http://www.json.org/ seems to be a good instruction.
It's just like that:

```
{
    "key1" : "value",
    "key2" : 123,
    "key3" : [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "key4" : {
        "key5" : "value",
        "key6" : "other value"
    }
}
```

{ } define an object, and [ ] an array.

Comment: Really, all in all, there isn't much more to it except that keys can be defined without the quotes if need be.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/)

It's really a pretty simple concept. You have Objects and Arrays, and a few primitive datatypes (strings, numbers, booleans, and null).

Add commas, curly brackets, and square brackets.

I really like it's simplicity, I can write my own parser for it without too much hassle pretty easily if needed (Which usually is not the case due to so many libraries for it out there).